# How to correctly query a Firebase Realtime Database Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

Im really new to firebase realtime databases and i didnt have time to learn it thoroughly before starting a school project. The queries are not working properly.

I have a database that looks like the following:

```
{
  "cat": {
    "-NKKUp_AiD98WHUvnfR0": {
      "birthYear": "2001",
      "imageUrl": "***",
      "name": "Tom"
    }
  },
  "user": {
    "uFkR1Z1UoVTVUmbpDmgU7BXGT852": {
      "admin": true,
      "email": "ziaddddd@gmail.com",
      "fullName": "ziad212",
      "phoneNo": "011111111"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to create a new node 'request' and set its children to the current uId, the cat name, and the userName. but im having trouble with the user name. Here is my code:

```
static requestCat(catName) async {
    final uId = AuthenticationRepository.auth.currentUser!.uid;
    Query query = DbHelper.database.ref('user').orderByValue().equalTo(uId);

    final snapshot = await query.get();
    final user = snapshot.value as Map;

    user['key'] = snapshot.key;
    var userName = user['fullName'];
    DatabaseReference ref = DbHelper.database.ref('request');

    ref.push().set(
      {'catName': catName, 
      'userName': userName, 
      'userId': uId
      }
    );
  }
}
```

It gives me the following error when i call the funtion:

```
Error: [firebase_database/index-not-defined] Index not defined, add ".indexOn": ".value", for path "/user", to the rules
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49  throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/schedule_microtask.dart 49:5
_startMicrotaskLoop
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 166:15           <fn>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you need to [add an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) to your database to allow this query. You can do this in the security rules of your database, typically in the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/_/rules). For this specific query, the rules would be:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ...
    "user": {
      ".indexOn": ".value";
    }
  }
}
```